# win7 + vc7.1 + mfc = stackoverflow

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I've moved my vc7.1 project from WInXP to Win7. After rebuilding i got stackoverflow error in function _malloc_dbg when i start the program.

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x0051bf0f in XXX.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow."

----------------------
Call stack:
> msvcr71d.dll!_malloc_dbg(unsigned int nSize=140, int nBlockUse=2, const char * szFileName=0x10267784, int nLine=163)

  msvcr71d.dll!_calloc_dbg(unsigned int nNum=1, unsigned int nSize=140, int nBlockUse=2, const char * szFileName=0x10267784, int nLine=163)

  msvcr71d.dll!_mtinit()

  msvcr71d.dll!_CRTDLL_INIT(void * hDllHandle=0x10200000, unsigned long dwReason=1, void * lpreserved=0x0018fd24)

----------------------
```

I tried to set up different stacksizes in project options (from 10 to 100 mbytes), in all cases i got this error.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you have any warning when you compile ?

Comment: I got a lot of it.
Working in WinXP i hadn't any warnings, now i have warnings like
1. warning C4312: 'type cast' : conversion from 'int' to 'void *' of greater size
2. warning C4267: '=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data

Comment: It probably goes without saying, but you should probably solve those issues first.  Are you now building as 64-bit and previously as 32-bit?

Comment: >Are you now building as 64-bit and previously as 32-bit
I'd been working in 32-bit WinXP, now i have 64-bit Win7, but i build my project as 32-bit application.

Comment: The last Visual Studio version that's compatible with Vista/Win7 is VS2005.  It's been 7 years, time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Warnings like "conversion from 'int' to 'void *' of greater size" and "conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data" almost certainly mean you're accidentally compiling your application as 64-bit. What they're trying to say is that the size of int (typically 32 bits) and size_t or void* are differing. In a 32-bit compile size_t would usually be the same size as int while in 64-bit it may be 64 bits. The same applies with pointer types like void*.

I would first double check that your application is in fact building in 32-bit mode. Is there something like unix "file" you can run to check the executable format?

Once that's checked I can think of two possible reasons for stack overflow: Since the code you show is in malloc, perhaps you have a latent heap memory bug that's just show up now in the new environment. If it's trashing a portion of the stack it could look like it overflowed.

Alternately you could be inadvertently infinitely recursing (again, possibly due to a subtle change in build environment) and actually using up all your stack. Infinite recursion can use up stack space remarkably fast.